# Put data from file to array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file

here's my code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    //Vars
    FILE *fp;
    char word[9999],
        *arrayOfWords[9999];
    int wordCount = 0, i;
    //Actions
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if(fp != NULL) {
        while(!feof(fp)) {
            fscanf(fp, "%s", word);
            arrayOfWords[wordCount] = word;
            wordCount++;
        }
        for(i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
            printf("%s \n", arrayOfWords[i]);
        }
    puts("");
    } else {
        puts("Cannot read the file!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to read some data from a text file and store it into an array.
Everything is fine while I'm in the loop, but when I get out of there, any value of any index in my array is filled with the last word of the file. Could anyone help me find out mistakes I am doing?

Data file:

```
Hello there, this is a new file.
```

Result:

```
file.
file.
file.
file.
file.
file.
file.
file.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are atleast 2 points of concern in your code. `char word[9999], *arrayOfWords[9999];` defines `arrayOfWords` to be an array of 9999 `char pointers`. This is one point of concern.

Another point is `arrayOfWords[wordCount] = word;`. Here to store the newly read word, you need to allocate space as `arrayOfWords` is an array of pointers. Please find your modified code as below.

```
int main() {
//Vars
FILE *fp;
char arrayOfWords[30];
int wordCount = 0, i;
//Actions
fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
if(fp != NULL) {
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", &arrayOfWords[wordCount]);
        wordCount++;
    }
    puts("");
    for(i = 0; i < (wordCount - 1); i++) {
        puts(arrayOfWords[i]);
    }
puts("");
} else {
    puts("Cannot read the file!");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for each individual member of your array(using malloc or by giving a second dimension of the array and declaring it of type `char` instead of `char*`). What you do is similar to:

```
char *s;
scanf("%s", s);
```

And this can not work in `C`. In fact here you have UB(undefined behavior), because the pointer is not initialized.

EDIT: you get all the fields in the array to point to your array `word` instead, once you have read word you should allocate new memory for the string and then `strcpy` `word` into it.

Comment: I just realized I pasted the wrong piece of code. Edited. But I guess it's still the same. I just don't get why every index of array has the correct value while it's in the loop.

Comment: I have edited your answer and now I know why all the fields have the same value - they in fact all point to `word` and that also explains why they all store the last values read. Try it out - modify word and check that all values also change.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
arrayOfWords[wordCount] = word;
```

does not copy the current word into separate storage, it merely assigns another pointer to point to the same piece of storage that `word` does. So you end up with an array of pointers to the same `word` array. You need to separately allocate memory for each word and copy the characters that make up each word (and the NULL terminator), rather than the pointer.